# How to use png's in ggplot2 plots?

Tags: r, ggplot2, png

I have a simple plot:

```
require(tidyverse)

plot  <-   data_frame(
          year = 1:4,
          value = c(5,3,6,7)
        ) %>% 
          ggplot(aes(year,value))+
          geom_point()
    plot
```

Is it possible to use an icon to take the place of the points on the plot? Specifically this icon? 
[image]
It can be downloaded [here.](https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/41967/hand_man_mens_room_person_user_icon#size=128)

Comment: Indeed, my question is a duplicate of these.

Comment: Also see the [`ggimage` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggimage/vignettes/ggimage.html).